# How to create dynamic library for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am aware of this question being raised, but my concern here is that my application is not going to app store, rather its just for in-house development. I want to create a dynamic library (not static library) for my project. The problem where I am having issues in creating static library is that, I am bundling two unity asset's into two different frameworks, however few contents of such framework is similar, and at the last compile time, I am getting many duplicates. I tried -all_load for other flags, but still no go.

This is how my project is laid out:

```
Project -> Frameworkone -> UnityAssetone
        -> Frameworktwo -> UnityAssettwo
```

If I compile my project without any of any framework, it compiles fine, however if I put together, I am having issues of duplicate symbols. The concern is that in Unity assets, besides the "Data", there are subsets of the library that are dedicated to particular asset, and is not "Common" to any asset. Therefore, I thought if it would be possible to create dynamic sets of libraries to avoid duplicates, OR if there is any another approach to get rid of such duplicates, will really appreciate to know that.

Comment: Check this links: 1. [Create a 'dll' in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280393/create-a-dll-in-objective-c) 2. [Creating an iPhone library/framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696051/creating-an-iphone-library-framework) 3. [Creating a Static Library for iPhone](http://www.amateurinmotion.com/articles/2009/02/08/creating-a-static-library-for-iphone.html) 4. [Creating static library for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348051/creating-static-library-for-iphone)

Comment: @ViTo - interesting approach to see how to bind dynamic libraries as dylib, however since they are just executing at runtime with no header, I think I will have to segregating runtime contents vs instantiation of UnityView in framework. My concern is, how do I link one particular framework with its dedicated dylib? :)